# Mockito Maven Dependency - Nested POM packaging

Tags: maven, package, pom.xml

I have a project where I have a dependency on a POM packaged project

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>my.external</groupId>
   <artifactId>all-ext-libs</artifactId>
   <type>POM</type>
   <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

the above dependency has the following POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>my.external</groupId>
        <artifactId>mvn-root</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>my.external</groupId>
    <artifactId>all-ext-libs</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-r${build.number}</finalName>

        <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>

        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${skipTestCompile}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                    <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skipTestCompile}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <file>${project.build.finalName}</file>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I do `mvn clean install -U` on the `my.external` project, it only downloads JUnit dependency, but not mockito. I have confirmed that mockito doesn't exist in my `.m2` repo.

When did a dependency tree, it did pop up, but when I delete it from .m2 cache and do `mvn clean install -U` it doesn't get downloaded:

```
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-7:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- sslext:sslext:jar:1.2-0:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.struts:struts-tiles:jar:1.3.8:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-doxia-tools:jar:1.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19:test
```

I have been using maven for a while, and if my understanding is correct, it's merely a tool which downloads and manages dependencies. but if I asked it to download something, it will download/manage it such that the dependency is visible to my target application.

So why is it that it refuses to be downloaded when added into the `my.external` project. Because the JUnit downloads fine and it has the same packaging (POM).

Comment: Please share the full pom file of your pom typed my.external project...

Answer (score 0):

Your `all-ext-libs` has junit and mockito-all as *test* dependencies. These are not transitive and therefore ignored when you draw them transitively through a pom. I would expect that both of them are ignored when you build your original project.

My guess is that junit comes in through some other path and not through `all-ext-libs`.

The way to go:

- Create a pom with all your test dependencies
- Mark them all as `compile` in this pom.
- Add `<scope>test</scope>` when you reference the pom.

Comment: Not sure that's the case. Because I tried by removing JUnit and do a `mvn clean install -U` doesn't download Junit.

Comment: Could you post the `dependency:tree?` or at least the relevant parts of it?

Comment: Are you sure this is the only place in the dependency tree that mentions `junit`?

Comment: yes I am quite sure. And I tried keeping the scope to "blank" i.e. no scope.

Comment: I still think that transitive test dependencies should be ignored. We probably need the whole pom, dependency:tree and dependency:list to really understand the problem.